# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context' - ANN Visualizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting this error when trying to run Ann Visualizer from Anaconda/Jupyter. I have read several threads on this site and others and can't seem to make the error go away:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-bdba1202aeda> in <module>
      1 from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz
      2 
----> 3 ann_viz(model, title="VOC Neural Network")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ann_visualizer\visualize.py in ann_viz(model, view, filename, title)
     29     """
     30     from graphviz import Digraph;
---> 31     import keras;
     32     from keras.models import Sequential;
     33     from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten;

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     23 
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 25 from keras import models
     26 
     27 from keras.engine.input_layer import Input

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\models.py in <module>
     17 
     18 import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
---> 19 from keras import backend
     20 from keras import metrics as metrics_module
     21 from keras import optimizer_v1

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\keras\backend.py in <module>
     35 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_coordinator as dc
     36 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_coordinator_context as dc_context
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.eager.context import get_config
     38 from tensorflow.python.framework import config
     39 from keras import backend_config

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.context'
```

My Tensorflow/Keras versions are 2.4.0 when I run

```
print("Tensorflow : " + tf.__version__)
print("Keras : " + keras.__version__)
```

But in the Anaconsa environment it says 2.3.0 - Not sure if that's a factor?

I'm aware the ANN Visualizer only runs with Tensorflow > 2.1

I updated all my library calls to `from tensorflow import keras` (for example)

I'm not really sure what to do next - does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance for any help you can give..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from tensorflow.python.eager.context import get_config` Works fine with Tensorflow 2.5.

Install Tensorflow 2.5

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.5
```